# Ex-wife might been checking my computer - MacOs Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: login, history, screensaver

So I need to find out at what time "someone" might have typed in my password to unlock the screen saver, is there any way?

I tried the last command in terminal and checked some of the logfiles in command with no success.

As per the title this is on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: That's why you shouldn't share your password! Why don't you just change the password?

Answer (score 1):

Focused towards MacOS Catalina, may or may not work with other versions of MACOS.

1. A)

   create a script and call it something like display_access.sh and copy the following into it,save and run using your preferred method...

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   PERIOD=1d
   if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
       PERIOD=$1
   fi
   echo "Times of Mac screen lock and unlock events in the past ${PERIOD}:"
   SEARCH_FOR="going inactive, create activity semaphore|releasing the activity semaphore"
   log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last ${PERIOD} | grep -E "${SEARCH_FOR}" | cut -c '1-32 141-155'
   ```

   B) OR substitute this line for the last line in order to view the latest login events:

   ```
   log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last 1m | less
   ```

   change to any number of your choosing....
2. a)  Open Terminal
   If you are not logged in as an admin, then use su username to first authenticate as admin "username". (Use this proc to check login history On Mac without having to log current user out and disrupt current desktop if necessary).

b)  type `log show --last 1d | grep "UserActivity Assertion"`

- If you want to see more or less history back in time, change the "1d" to "2h" or "10m" (see documentation by running man log).
- If you omit the `--last` modifier, it will take a really long time to run, maybe more than 10 minutes.
  This seems to reliably show each time the machine was woken from sleep by the user unlocking the lock screen with their password.

3. Create this script for the seconds since the last unlock/lock:

   ```
   function  getlastunlock-darwin() {
       date="$(log show --style syslog --predicate 'process == "loginwindow"' --debug --info --last 1d | command rg "going inactive, create activity semaphore|releasing the activity semaphore" | tail -n1 |cut -c 1-31)" fromnow
   }
   function fromnow() {
       python3 -c 'import datetime ; from dateutil.parser import parse ; import os
   date = parse(os.environ["date"])
   print((datetime.datetime.now(date.tzinfo) - date).total_seconds())'
   }
   ```
4. Open terminal and type

   ```
    last
   ```

   this should provide log info

On a side note if you determine that someone is surreptitiously accessing your machine it may be an excellent opportunity to influence the situation with favorable information or information that might be advantageous to your cause. (ie flattery, info traps or outright misinformation. Is all fair in love and war?

May want to consult a lawyer? Police?

Change your password?

Delete last hour of history, logoff this site and use reasonable security so as not to "tip your hand"?

Try not to have a hasty reaction. (probably best to not divulge knowledge of the illicit access if you do find out your suspicions are correct as it will, obviously, be more useful to you in an 'unacknowldged' state, if you catch my meaning. Blowing up about it never helps the sitrep and usually makes it MUCH worse).

Best regards.